# How can I order a list of objects that contains Dates in c#

Tags: c#

I´m making a program that opens a file at certain hour. The user can choose the time, the date or the day of week or can combine them, between other things. The date and the time are strings and not DateTime because the user can also enter blank spaces, for instance, "__-03-2016" means that it will be executed everyday of March, 2016. The program has a coutdown clock that indicates the time remaining to next execution and here is my question: how can I know which object contains the "date" nearest now. How can this be done?
Here is the constructor of my class:

```
public Hours(string time, int intT, string date, int intDt, int day, int intDy, string eachTime, int intET, string eachDate, int intED)
{
    this.time = time;
    this.intT = intT;
    this.date = date;
    this.intDt = intDt;
    this.day = day;
    this.intDy = intDy;
    this.eachTime = time;
    this.intET = intET;
    this.eachDate = eachDate;
    this.intED = intED;
}
```

Comment: I would first calculate the next time each script has to be run. Than just sort them and take the one with the lowest datetime.

Comment: using Date difference functions.

Comment: You should convert your string into Date format then you can easily use any type of operators > = < <=, `Date.Now.Month >= Dateofyourcase.Month`